# Como garantir que a instanciação de uma classe seja feita apenas através do "using"?

Tags: c#, .net, using

Estou criando uma DLL com algumas funcionalidades de banco de dados (ADO.Net). Seria muito conveniente garantir que sempre seja usada a instanciação de conexões apenas via `using` (bloco), para não esquecer de chamar o `Dispose()`/`Close()`. Mas também é possível esquecer de usar o `using`.

Como garantir que o `using` seja usado em todas as classes com implementação do `IDisposable`?

Comment: A pergunta não estava muito clara e editei baseado nos seus comentários, veja se ficou melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas dentro de um `using`, não.

A ideia é que o Garbage Collector do .NET é capaz de detectar quando um objeto não será mais usado dentro do contexto da aplicação, expirando e eliminando o objeto sozinho. Claro que utilizando o `Dispose` é muito mais elegante, mas isso não tem como ser exigido.

Comment: Talvez não tenha ficado claro, mas o uso do "apenas" na pergunta é no sentido de não permitir a instanciação da classe se não for por meio do bloco using.

Comment: @CaiqueC. Reformulei.

Answer (score 3):

É recomendado que se faça desta forma sempre que uma classe implementar a interface [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-5.0). Infelizmente o compilador e nem o Visual Studio ajudam garantir isto. Até entendo que o compilador não obrigue porque há raros casos legítimos que não se deve usar esta forma.

Mas uma ferramenta adicional configurável deveria ajudar. Por sorte existe o [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) que pode te alertar que sempre que a classe que você está instanciando não está em um [`using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101). É a única forma que eu conheço mas outros *plugins* concorrentes dele devem ter algo semelhante. Obviamente o alerta é feito apenas para classes que implementam o `IDisposable`.

Também é possível personalizar o novo [.NET Compiler Platform](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/dotnet-compiler-platform) para fazer isto. Não tenho dados para informar como fazer isto e não deve ser muito trivial, apesar de também não ser muito complexo. A ideia da nova plataforma do compilador é justamente deixar as pessoas estenderem o seu funcionamento conforme suas necessidades.