# Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?

Tags: c#, .net, gerenciamento-de-memória, dispose, using

De acordo com a documentação da Microsoft:

> A instrução using fornece uma sintaxe conveniente que garante o uso
> correto dos IDisposable objetos.
>
> [Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Ou seja, a interface [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) fornece um mecanismo para liberar recursos não gerenciados e com a declaração `using` podemos automatizar este processo de liberação de recursos.

Agora vamos a um exemplo real da implementação da declaração `using`.

Método responsavel por listar todos os clientes do banco de dados:

```
public static List<Cliente> ListarTodos()
{
    var clientes = new List<Cliente>();
    var stringConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLStringConnection"].ConnectionString;

    try
    {
        using (var conexao = new MySqlConnection(stringConnection))
        {
            conexao.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand commad = conexao.CreateCommand())
            {
                commad.CommandText = "select idcliente, nome, cpf from cliente;";

                using (var sqlReader = commad.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (sqlReader.Read())
                        {
                            clientes.Add(new Cliente
                            {
                                IdCliente = sqlReader.GetInt32(0),
                                Nome = sqlReader.GetString(1),
                                Cpf = sqlReader.GetString(2)
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    sqlReader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

    return clientes;
}
```

Repare que há varias declarações `using`s neste exemplo que irá liberar os recursos quando o objeto terminar de ser utilizado, e é exatamente neste ponto que surgi a minha dúvida que vem logo abaixo.

---

## Dúvida

Quando se fala em **recursos** que serão liberados, refere-se ao uso de memória e processador, ou é outros tipos de **recursos**? Se for outros tipos de **recursos**, eu gostaria de saber quais são esses tipos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nenhum tipo de recurso é liberado porque usou o comando (não confundir com a [diretiva de importação de nomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101)) `using`. A única coisa garantida que o `using` faz é chamar o método `Dispose()` de um objeto, portanto, conforme já dito na resposta, ele só pode ser usado em objetos que implementam `IDisposable`.

O que você faz dentro deste método não é determinado. Sim, a intenção é liberar recursos não gerenciados, mas não há garantias que isso seja feito. Em tese pode-se abusar.

## Exemplo

Pegando um exemplo de uma pergunta que respondi:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Create)) {
    // Algum código...
}
```

É o mesmo que:

```
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Create);
    try {
       // Algum código...
    } finally {
        if (fs != null)
            ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Esse exemplo é um arquivo que será aberto, vinculado à aplicação, terá algum recurso de memória alocado pelo sistema operacional, e não pela aplicação .NET, o sistema operacional obviamente controla todo esse acesso, e em algum momento ele precisará ser fechado, ou seja, precisa dizer para o sistema operacional que não precisa mais disto e que ele pode fazer o que quiser com o recurso. Se tiver curiosidade em [ver o fonte desse `Dispose()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,8270a043211dafd8,references) e seguir até onde vai.

## Recursos

Esses recursos não são de processador, pelo menos não em condições normais, nem acho que faça sentido nesse contexto. Também não são de memória diretamente. Embora seja muito comum que esses recursos possam estar em memória, isso faz parte de algo maior, é algo que a sua aplicação não tem controle direto. Obviamente que todo recurso fisicamente só existe para você em forma de um trecho de memória, mas o recurso não é só isso, é tudo o que está em volta da administração desse trecho. Na verdade abstratamente nem podemos pensar nisso, isso é um detalhe que não tem importância.

#### De onde eles vêm

É comum que esse recursos sejam:

- um arquivo (em disco ou não) ou outra forma de acesso ao sistema operacional, como memória mapeada ou *pipes*,
- um acesso ao sistema de janelas dele,
- uma simples fonte tipográfica, que é um misto algumas coisas, assim como um pincel gráfico,
- qualquer coisa que o sistema operacional possa disponibilizar, incluindo aí recursos de rede, ou um "simples" [Mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) ([fonte da classe](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/mutex.cs,29b92e0e2832a8d6)).

Em geral isso é feito através de uma API de baixo nível, normalmente disponibilizada para uso com C (a maioria das linguagens conseguem acessá-las por alguma forma de [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface).

Também diversos serviços instalados na máquina podem oferecer recursos, pode ser um servidor HTTP ou um banco de dados, uma aplicação sua que tenha uma API que não conforme com o .NET.

### Porque precisam ser descartados

Em geral todos esses recursos possuem uma forma de fechamento, de liberação, de remoção que precisa ser chamada quando não se deseja mais o seu uso. Se esse mecanismo não for chamado ele ficará anexado à sua aplicação, provavelmente ocupando memória que o *garbage collector* do .NET não cuida, inclusive existe a possibilidade de deixar algo travado para outro uso, ou ter outras consequências indesejáveis.

Note que se o objeto tem um `Dispose()` ele será chamado mais cedo ou mais tarde - se não acontecer nada muito trágico na aplicação - e fará a liberação do recurso mesmo que você não tenha usado o `using` ou o chamado manualmente (não recomendado na maioria das situações), mas poderá fazer mais tarde do que se pretende e gerar problemas. O `using` garante que ocorra tão logo o recurso não seja mais necessário, aconteça o que acontecer dentro da normalidade da aplicação (mesmo que tenha uma exceção comum).

Mesmo que o sistema quebre inesperadamente é claro que o recurso será liberado, uma aplicação morta não pode segurar recursos,  isso é garantido pelo sistema operacional.

Estamos falando da necessidade de liberar algo assim que ele não seja mais necessária. Lembrando que o coletor de lixo pode rodar quando precisar apenas, não há garantias de chamada. Em tese você pode fazer em qualquer classe sua, mas seria um abuso e não traria maiores benefícios, tentar liberar memória gerenciada com ele não dá certo, por ser gerenciada pelo [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101), não tem nada que você possa fazer para liberá-la, se precisa disto (não imagino um caso que faça sentido) terá que pensar em outra solução. Na maior parte dos casos só é necessário em classes de mais baixo nível.

Há casos que não liberar o recurso não é um problema. Em geral em aplicações de execução efêmera e simples, é o que eu falo sempre sobre PHP. As pessoas se preocupam com regras e se esquecem que existem exceções.

## C# 8

Um detalhe interessante é que agora (C# 8) não precisa mais criar blocos para o `using`, só declarar a variável sem o bloco e o escopo passa ser o bloco atual. Só isto:

```
using var fs = new FileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Create);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/UsingPattern.cs).

## Conclusão

No exemplo da pergunta todos os casos de alguma forma estão atrelados ao banco de dados. Uma conexão, por exemplo, é algo que a sua aplicação não tem controle. Ela precisa ser "abandonada" o mais rápido possível (em geral), não pode esperar o GC trabalhar para avisar que não precisa mais disto. Bom, eu costumo manter a conexão ativa, sempre que dá, e não precisa jogar fora, mas eu não sigo regras, eu penso pra fazer.

- [Documentação sobre como criar um `Dispose()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [Quando devo usar GC.SuppressFinalize()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102609/101)

Comment: na verdade a atribuicao de `fs` é feita dentro do `try`

Comment: @BrunoCosta Você tem alguma fonte que mostre isso? Até onde eu sei é fora. Eu não me lembro de onde eu tirei isso, mas foi depois de muita pesquisa, é muito provável que seja informação do Eric Lippert, quem escreveu o compilador que faz isso. Eu vi que o pessoal costuma falar sem prestar atenção como realmente funciona. Mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: Depois de ter deixado o comentário cheguei á conclusao que nao faz diferenca mesmo, pelo pouco que tive a ver voce tem razao.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do @Maniero já fala em tudo sobre o `IDisposable`, eu vou apenas responder á pergunta de forma mais direta.

> Quando se fala em recursos que serão liberados, refere-se ao uso de
>   memória e processador, ou é outros tipos de recursos?

O objetivo do `IDisposable` é libertar qualquer tipo de recursos mesmo. Por exemplo:

- Acesso a ficheiros
- Ligacoes á base de dados
- Recursos nativos, incluindo memória `unmanaged` (se sua aplicao interoperar com aplicaoes `unmanaged`)
- Ligacoes de rede

Uma coisa que o @Maniero não mencionou:

Um objeto que implemente `IDisposable` deve garantir que depois de ser chamado `Dispose` não é possível operar com o objeto e deve lançar [`ObjectDisposedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception(v=vs.110).aspx). Este mesmo recurso é fonte da afirmação que acabei de dar.

Comment: Eu votei e fui pesquisar sobre *thread*, porque achei estranho, elas são gerenciadas pelo .Net e não precisam ser descartadas explicitamente. Na verdade o recurso da *thread* que é liberado é uma porção de memória para gerenciar seu *stack*, o recurso de processador é um algo adquirido, não é algo que ele seja dono, na verdade nem sei se o termo recurso pode ser usado nesse contexto (até ele é usado em outro). Mesmo que pense assim, o "recurso" utilizado pela *thread*, além de não ser reservado, pode nem estar sendo usado, mesmo a *thread* ainda existindo.

Comment: Mas *thread*  sequer implementa `IDisposable`

Comment: @bigown Eu sei, e apenas estranho quando o objeto e `Disposed` e a sua `thread` contiua a trabalhar, nao acha? Eu acho. Ou seja voce nao faz Dispose dela. Voce pode fazer `Abort` ou garantir de alguma forma que ela termina com `thread.join()` por exemplo

Comment: deixo aqui o comentario anterior: @bigown Eu apenas coloquei `thread` eventualmente por ser uma boa pratica. Se tudo o que seu objeto fizer o fizer numa thread separada por exemplo, nao faz sentido a `thread` continuar executando quando o objeto e `Disposed`.

Comment: Então acho uma pena eu ter votado na reposta, porque ela está errada, isso sequer faz sentido.

Comment: @bigown pode vir ao [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48121/room-for-bruno-costa-and-bigown)?

Comment: Não tenho paciência pra ficar discutindo isso, tenho experiência que vai ficar em círculos, eu disse o que precisava, você insistiu que sua resposta é essa, eu a considero errada pelos motivos que já escrevi. Achei que você entenderia que foi só um descuido e arrumaria, uma pena eu ter votado na confiança.

Comment: @bigown Vou resolver o problema fazendo uma pergunta entao. Creio que voce vai le-la e talvez ate responder a ela. Vou tambem editar esta resposta ate receber uma resposta a minha pergunta