# Devo asseguar que as threads terminam no Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, thread, dispose

Já existem algumas perguntas sobre a interface `IDisposable` e o `using`, por exemplo:

[Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração using](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163768/)

[Devo sempre utilizar o dispose](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22284/devo-sempre-utilizar-dispose)

Ainda assim eu não tenho a certeza do que fazer em relação as *threads*.

Na minha ideia se o objeto usa alguma *thread* explicitamente, faz todo o sentido garantir que essa *thread* termine com o uso do `thread.join()` por exemplo.

Isto serviria para garantir não há qualquer trabalho a executar em *background* mas também diminuiria os recursos (neste caso CPU) usado por essa *threads*.

Além disso eu também garantia que as *threads* estariam num estado conhecido (terminado), em vez de estarem num estado desconhecido.

Eu sei que o CPU não e um recurso que possa ser reservado pela *thread* e que não há nada que garanta que a minha *thread* o esteja a usar.

Mas a minha premissa e a seguinte: Se eu posso assegurar que não há trabalho a ser feito nas *threads*, porque não fazê-lo?

O que devo fazer afinal? Devo garantir que as minhas *threads* terminam ou não?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bruno, sempre que sua classe tiver membros que implementem `IDisposable` você **DEVE** fazer o 'dispose' correto destes membros na sua classe.

`Thread` não implementa `IDisposable`, portanto você não **DEVE**, mas você certamente **PODE** encerrar a thread, pelo motivos que você comentou.

Porém sugiro não utilizar diretamente um objecto Thread e sim utilizar recursos mais *modernos* como ThreadPool ou, melhor ainda, Task (TPL).

Comment: Entendi. É a tipica dualidade do **deve** vs **pode** encontrada em documentos *ISO*. Se calhar é um problema que **deve** ser resolvido noutro método para além do dispose

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Minelli já diz o básico, resolvi responder porque isso originou em uma pergunta da qual eu respondi e teve comentários meus.

Se a classe [`Thread`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) não implementa `IDisposable` não dá para chamar o `Dispose()` de forma alguma, por mais que se queira.

Pode ser até um problema de terminologia, mas terminar uma *thread* nada tem a ver com descartar seus recursos (*handle* do sistema operacional por exemplo). O `Dispose()` é para descartar, não para terminar.

Na pergunta [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101) que originou isso fala sobre o uso de `using`, portanto não existe a menor possibilidade do seu uso  na classe `Thread`, mesmo que queira. Você pode fazer alguma coisa para evitar que a *thread* se mantenha viva se quiser, mas não será com o `using`, não será chamando `Dispose()`. Sem dúvida é preciso tomar alguns cuidados com ela para garantir sua finalização, mas não é com `using`. É preciso garantir que ela seja parada, se assegurar isso, está tudo certo.

Porém criar *threads* é muito caro, não é adequado ficar criando ou matando elas. Precisa criar e reaproveitar o que tem. Para isso usamos tarefas sempre que possível. Ou criamos um mecanismo que simule mais ou menos o que `Task` faz. Uma tarefa pode ou não manipular *threads*, ela em si não faz isso, pode só precisar de algo assíncrono.

O fato de uma *thread* continuar existindo não significa que ela está consumindo algum recurso, ela pode estar em [estado parado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) sem consumir CPU algum, só consumirá memória para seu *stack* e algumas pequenas informações de administração dela.

Já se usar a classe [`Task`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), aí é diferente, essa classe pode, e normalmente deve usar o `using` ou um padrão que faça mais ou menos a mesma coisa que o `using` faz. Depois foi criada a [`ValueTask`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que não precisa, e ela é preferida sempre que possível.

Comment: Já consegui entender melhor qual é o dilema com a sua resposta. E chego então á conclusão que o trabalho de terminar uma `thread` deve ser feito noutro método. Tal como tinha sugerido no meu comentário á resposta do Mineli. Nao sei que resposta aceitar, preferi priveligiar o usuario com menos reputacao, uma vez que a respsota dele também é boa.