# Por que o garbage collector do .NET possui várias gerações?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, garbage-collector

Entendo o motivo de existir uma garbage collector, mas queria saber quais as vantagens de fazer ele ter várias gerações. Parece algo bem mais complicado, precisa ser muito vantajoso.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O GC é algo bem antigo, muito mais do que as pessoas imaginam. Este é um mecanismo estudado em profundidade por muita gente. Cada vez mais foram detectando os problemas e achando soluções.

## Problemas do GC

#### Pausa

Um dos problemas que esse mecanismo sempre teve foi a pausa quando ocorre a coleta. Ela pode ser longa e sem nenhuma restrição de tempo. Isso é algo que faz muita gente evitar o GC. Especialmente no *garbage collector* que faz *tracing* isso é um problema, ainda que mesmo outras técnicas possam sofrer deste e outros problemas que o *tracing* não sofre. Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre os problemas de outras técnicas já que o .NET usa um coletor de lixo rastreador.

Algumas técnicas foram pensadas para reduzir as pausas. Uma delas é a coleta incremental onde é possível determinar um tempo máximo que a coleta pode ocorrer. Ajuda bem, mas tem um problema, é comum ter muito retrabalho por "deixar o serviço pela metade". Existem algumas formas de minimizar isso, mas não é a solução mais adequada para muitos casos. Precisava de uma solução melhor para diminuir as pausas.

#### Fragmentação de memória

Também existe um problema no gerenciamento de memória que vale para qualquer aplicação, não importando a forma que gerencia. Conforme a aplicação vai alocando e liberando memória cria buracos de alocação. Isso tem dois problemas: há desperdício de memória porque muitos desses buracos não podem ser reaproveitados, e quando eles são reaproveitados, objetos que costumam ser usados juntos acabam sendo alocados distantes um do outro criando um problema de localidade de referência, o que pode degradar bastante a performance de acesso aos objetos.

A solução para os dois problemas foi o coletor de lixo geracional.

#### Outros problemas

Existem outros problemas que o mecanismo geracional não resolve, um deles é o indeterminismo da coleta. Há solução, é o [`using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101). É possível criar um coletor determinístico, mas é complicado demais e possui desvantagens.

## Gerações

#### Gen0

No GC geracional existe uma primeira geração onde os objetos pequenos são alocados sempre que são criados.

Esta geração costuma ser pequena. O .NET começa com 256KB (se não mudou). Esse tamanho vai sendo adaptado com o tempo conforme a necessidade da aplicação. O tamanho pode variar se a arquitetura é 32 ou 64 bits, e o tipo de GC que está habilitado e até a quantidade de *cores* da máquina.

Na verdade existem algumas arenas desse tamanho na geração 0. Uma para cada *core* da máquina. Desta forma a alocação nunca ocorre de forma concorrente e não precisa de travamentos para alocar, como é comum fazer em alocações no *heap*. Basta fazer o incremento do ponteiro que determina o fim daquela área de memória pré-alocada.

Isso é um enorme ganho de performance. O custo de alocar no GC no .NET é o mesmo de [alocar no *stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), que é muito rápido. Isso é algo fantástico.

Quando faz uma nova alocação e enche uma arena, a aplicação é congelada e começa uma coleta. Essa coleta é bem curta porque tem pouca coisa para coletar. Então a pausa não deve ser maior que alguns microssegundos.

Na verdade não é bem uma coleta que é feita. O que ocorre de fato é a cópia dos objetos para a próxima geração, a Gen1, que ainda possuem referência na aplicação. Em geral copia-se bem pouca coisa porque a maioria dos objetos morrem logo. Isso é chamado de **compactação**.

Isso é ótimo porque vai alocando tudo próximo e em sequência, evitando a fragmentação de memória. Não é ótimo? Resolve os dois problemas.

É muito comum que técnicas semiautomáticas como a contagem de referência ter performance pior que essa forma de GC enquanto há apenas coleta da Gen0. Pode ser mais rápido até que muita técnica manual de memória quando se analisa toda operação necessária e toda perda por causa da fragmentação.

Note que pode ser que uma coleta nunca seja chamada, o que é um enorme ganho. Mesmo quando tem coleta não há custo de liberação de memória, só há o custo da movimentação dos objetos ainda vivos. A liberação ocorre em toda uma arena de uma vez.

#### Gen1

Esta é uma área um pouco maior (começa em 2MB, mas depende de algumas circunstâncias) e só recebe objetos através da coleta da Gen0. Vai alocando tudo em sequência sem buracos. Só objetos com um certo tempo de vida chegarão aqui. Demora para ela encher.

Quando enche é disparada uma coleta que copiará os objetos sobreviventes para a Gen2. A pausa para a coleta não costuma ser maior que 1 milissegundo.

Essa coleta ocorre com raridade já que são poucos objetos que sobrevivem muito tempo.

Em alguns casos há mais performance na aplicação com GC mesmo coletando Gen1 se comparado com uma aplicação que faça tudo *reference counting*, ou até gerenciamento manual que não seja extremamente otimizado.

#### Gen2

Esta é a última geração que recebe objetos que tendem a sobreviver por muito tempo, ou até mesmo o tempo todo. O ideal é que esta geração não tenha muitas coletas, ou nunca ocorra. Ela não tem limite de tamanho e a sua pausa pode levar não só muitos milissegundos, mas também vários segundos (raro, explico abaixo).

Na prática existem segmentos (16 ou 256MB) então a coleta de cada vez pode ter um certo limite. Não sei se está funcionando assim no momento, mas é possível que só o segmento que encheu seja coletado.

As gerações mais jovens costumam ficar dentro de um segmento destes.

A coleta pode ser feita de forma concorrente, o que não impede a aplicação continuar funcionando sem pausa. Na verdade tem uma pausa para fazer a verificação dos objetos ainda referenciados, mas é um tempo bem curto. Isso é possível porque a aplicação não pode alocar nessa área diretamente.

[image: GC concorrente]

Essa coleta move os objetos na própria área da Gen2 e isso pode gerar uma mínima fragmentação em alguns casos. Nada crítico.

Aqui é onde a performance pode se tornar um problema em GC, mas pelo menos a pausa pode ser bem minimizada se tiver mais de um *core* na máquina. Mesmo com apenas um *core* é possível melhorar a experiência.

Muito raramente ela precisa ser feita. Enquanto tiver memória sobrando não há necessidade de coletá-la (depende de configuração).

Se tiver memória suficiente é possível até mesmo ter mais performance com GC do que sem ele.

#### LOH

Os objetos acima de 85000 bytes entram em outra área chamada *Large Object Heap*. Esta área tem coleta normal e libera a memória de objetos grandes que não são mais referenciados. Essa coleta ocorre junto com a coleta da Gen2. Em geral provoca fragmentação (tem uma configuração que a evita, mas tem desvantagens em usar).

Quase impossível um objeto normal entrar nessa área. Grande parte dos *arrays* (mesmo os internalizados dentro de algum tipo) entram nessa área. Só depende do tamanho.

Isso é útil porque movimentar objetos grandes pode custar muito. Algo que colaborou bastante para Java ter a fama de lenta por muito tempo.

Ela é colocada em segmentos.

#### POH

No .NET 5 passar ter também o *Pinned Object Heap* que armazena todos objetos que são pinados, diminuindo assim a fragmentação do resto do *heap* já que esses objeto não podem ser movidos, assim eles são segregados.

## Conclusão

Por tudo isso dizemos que os objetos em .NET devem morrer jovens ou viver para sempre, assim não precisam ser coletados.

As gerações resolvem o problema da pausa e fragmentação de memória, além de dar mais performance no gerenciamento de memória.

Não dá para fazer uma aplicação 100% *real time* (até existem GCs assim: [*paper*](http://www.jopdesign.com/doc/nbgc.pdf)) com o GC, mas pode fazer jogos, tem GUI suave sem congelamentos.

Se ainda precisar reduzir mais as pausas aí tem que começar usar técnicas específicas de alocação, como *object pool* ou abuso de `structs` no lugar de classes, técnica facilitada no C# 7.

Grosso modo é isso. Tem uma série de detalhes que não acho que sirva o propósito desta pergunta.

Se quiser mais detalhes tem um [artigo muito bom](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/understanding-different-gc-modes-with-concurrency-visualizer/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estava lendo esse post e acabei criando um pergunta relacionada a consumo de memória.  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200836/consumo-excessivo-de-mem%C3%B3ria-ou-memory-leak-na-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 2):

O garbage collector coleta os objetos de vida curta com mais freqüência do que os de longa duração. Os objetos de vida curta são armazenados na primeira geração, geração 0. Os objetos de vida mais longa são empurrados para as gerações superiores, 1 ou 2. O garbage collector funciona mais freqüentemente nas gerações mais baixas do que nas mais altas.

Este trecho foi retirado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257563/what-are-the-generations-in-garbage-collection que por sua vez usou como fonte http://aspalliance.com/828