# Linguagem com Garbage Collector pode ser usada para jogos?

Tags: java, c#, .net, jogos, garbage-collector

Comecei aprender C# e até Java por interesse em desenvolvimento de jogos. Mas sei que muitos são desenvolvidos com C++, principalmente por não ter um *garbage collector*. Claro que eu sei que vários jogos são feitos em C# e Java.

Imagino que seja a pausa que causa problema. O que eu quero saber mesmo é como é resolvida a pausa no desenvolvimento de um jogo feito nestas linguagens.

Comment: Também tenho interesse em jogos e nessas linguagens - não entendi por que "a pausa" causaria qualquer problema - de que pausa você está falando?

Comment: @DanielGomes vc aparece no cenário em uma máquina, manda pra outra essa informação, o outro jogador verá você pra atirar, mas antes de mostrar começa uma coleta, o jogo atrasa por causa disto, aí aparece, ele dá um tiro, só que na sua máquina não teve pausa, você não está mais ali. Você deve tomar o tiro? Fica esquisito. Se não deve o outro jogador não conseguiu te matar porque o software não deixou e não por causa na inabilidade dele.

Comment: A linguagem Go tem dedicado muito esforço a diminuir a pausa causada pelo coletor de lixo, de modo a não ser um problema.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Qualquer linguagem que use um [coletor de lixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101) em sistemas [*real time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) terá problemas porque o tempo de liberação da memória não é determinístico, que é uma característica fundamental para sistema em tempo real. Mesmo em memória manual é um problema quando há cascata ou o algoritmo de alocação ou liberação é eficiente em economia de memória e pode ter dificuldade de lidar com a [*free list*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list) de memória. Quando tem uso de memória dinâmica o *real time* de verdade não é possível.

Aplicações semi *real time* já ficam mais fáceis porque ninguém morrerá se tiver um pequeno atraso eventual. É o caso de jogos. Os *frames* precisam ser atualizados em tempo controlado e não pode ocorrer uma operação longa demais que faça perder o momento correto de atualização.

Um GC ingênuo certamente traz sérios problemas para jogos, mas não um geracional, que é o caso de C# ou Java.

A coleta da [Gen0 é muito rápida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200713/101), no computo geral costuma ser mais rápido que o gerenciamento manual de memória no *heap*, fora o ganho que pode obter pela localidade de referência.

A Gen1 não é tão boa, mas é curta e com tempo máximo mais ou menos definido. Desde que esse tempo seja considerado dá para manter uma confiabilidade.

A Gen2 é o problema, mas é bem minimizado já que ela é feito em *background* com a execução normal da aplicação. Em máquinas com mais de 1 *core* a pausa pode ser bem curta como nas gerações anteriores.

Deve saber que vários jogos são feitos em C#, principalmente com [Unity](https://unity3d.com/pt/). E eles têm bastante sucesso no gerenciamento de memória.

Infelizmente C# não pod<strike>e</strike>(ia) configurar muita coisa no GC e não pode trocar o GC facilmente como o Java permite, ainda que as alternativas mais apropriadas para *real time* ainda costumam ser bem caras ($). O [.NET Core não dá tanta facilidade, mas pode trocar por um outro coletor de lixo ou mudar pequenos detalhes](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/gc). O Mono também permite configurar e trocar o GC. Outras implementações como a do XBox, Compact e Micro Framework podem ter GC determinístico (não sei como está hoje), mas provavelmente não usará os últimos para para jogos. De fato agora [só sobreviveu o .NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

## Técnicas de otimização

A maioria do que vou dizer aqui vale para qualquer linguagem ([C ou C++ por exemplo podem ser mais rápidas, mais controladas, mas ninguém diz que dá um trabalho monstro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101)), uma com *garbage collector* só precisa de mais cuidado. Em alguns pontos as linguagens com memória gerenciada são até melhores.

- [Evite usar o *heap* tanto quanto possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), assim não tem o custo da coleta ou liberação. C# tem cada vez mais recursos para preferir a pilha.
- Entenda como cada componente funciona e saiba onde ocorre alocações, especialmente aquelas que costumam ser invisíveis ao programador como [*boxing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing). Você só pode evitar alocações se souber que elas existem ([exemplo de como evitar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101)).
- Se usar o *heap* procure fazer pré-alocações que nunca serão liberadas, use os chamados [*Object Pool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) (veja a ótima explicação do Luiz Vieira) ou [*Flyweight Pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/101). Tem estruturas que já funcionam como *pools* se quiser, um exemplo é `List` onde você pode limpar em vez de apagar, assim mantém a alocação já feita para um novo uso da lista. Se apagar, gera um lixo e depois vai gerar outro objeto para essa nova lista.
- Faça o código menos orientado a objeto que abusam de referências.
- Nunca esqueça que os objetos devem morrer jovens ou viver para sempre.
- Em alguns casos precisará construir suas próprias estruturas de dados ou utilizar bibliotecas de terceiros que sejam mais adequadas para a necessidade. O novo compilador do C# tem um monte de estrutura que parece duplicação do que já existe no .NET, mas elas foram escritas para a necessidade do compilador.
- Em caso extremo [aloque fora da memória gerenciada](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads). Aí ela passa ser problema seu gerenciar, mas é uma forma de ter controle quando a liberação ocorrerá. Só cuidado pra não vazar memória. C#, ao contrário de Java permite você gerenciar a memória quando não há outra solução melhor.
- Use [`TryStartNoGCRegion()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_GC_TryStartNoGCRegion_System_Int64_) sempre que houver um momento que não pode ter uma coleta, não é garantindo, mas ajuda.
- Sabendo fazer, [chamar a coleta manualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101) quando está entre fases, pausa ou algo que não atrapalha ter uma pausa, pode minimizar a chance de pause durante a ação do jogo. Mas se fizer errado pode piorar a situação.
- Não esqueça de manter configurado para usar o modo Workstation que diminui as pausas.
- [Perfile](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153878/101) a aplicação para descobrir onde está o problema.
- Especifique uma boa quantidade mínima de memória. GC trabalha melhor quando tem memória sobrando.
- Faça as *threads* ajudarem na organização do software (algo bem mais avançado).
- Tem técnicas de manter o jogo em atraso para evitar surpresas, mas isso não é simples de fazer corretamente e não resolve sempre.

Veja [Como identificar e evitar memory leak no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186644/101).

Em suma, produza menos lixo e faça o GC trabalhar a seu favor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta (mesmo não sendo eu a perguntar). Mas sabe me dizer como ficam os objetos carregados em uma cena no Unity, depois que essa cena se acaba? Por exemplo: Ao entrar em uma cena aonde é o "campo de futebol". Quando o jogo acaba, e você volta pro menu, saberia me dizer se a memória alocada pelo "campo de futebol" é totalmente liberada? Sei que aqui nesse comentário fiquei meio fora de contexto, mas estive procurando sobre e não achei coisas muito satisfatórias para ler.

Comment: @ArturoTemplário Sobre Unity sei quase nada.

Comment: @ArturoTemplário, eu particularmente nunca fiz um jogo tão grande assim, então sei pouco... Na Unity, ela só carrega os objetos da cena quando você manda carregar a cena; então, isso significa que ela vai evitar criar o futebol antes que você o mande fazer isso. Sobre abandonar cenas existentes (depois da partida, por exemplo), você precisa falar para a Unity fazer isso `SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync`. Assets precisam ser liberados separadamente: `Resources.UnloadAllUnusedAssets`. Mais detalhes em [SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html)

Answer (score 18):

> *Comecei aprender C# e até Java por interesse em desenvolvimento de
>   jogos. Mas sei que muitos são desenvolvidos com C++, principalmente
>   por não ter um garbage collector.*

Isso não é necessariamente verdade. Muitos jogos são (ou eram) desenvolvidos em C++ primeiramente pelos motivos de portabilidade e desempenho. Só que essa realidade tem mudado consideravelmente com os motores de jogos como a Unity3D. Hoje é mais comum desenvolver o jogo quase todo numa dessas ferramentas, e usar C++ apenas para código crítico (por exemplo, algum teste de colisão especial que precisa ser feito, ou algum cálculo de Inteligência Artificial). Como já lhe foi bem explicado em outras respostas, mesmo uma linguagem em que não se tem GC vc pode ter problemas se planejar incorretamente o uso da memória.

> *Claro que eu sei que vários jogos são feitos em C# e Java.*

Justamente por causa da produtividade obtida com ferramentas e/ou bibliotecas que usam essas linguagens. Mas eu ainda duvido que o principal motivador de uso seja a existência ou não do GC.

> *Imagino que seja a pausa que causa problema. O que eu quero saber mesmo é como é resolvida a pausa no desenvolvimento de um jogo feito nestas linguagens.*

Eu não entendi de que pausa você se refere. Seria a pausa do jogo, ou o intervalo que o GC leva pra remover a memória não mais referenciada? Se você se referia à primeira, não há razão para isso ser um problema pois durante esse tempo nenhum objeto é criado ou deletado (supostamente, claro - afinal, vc pode ter cometido erros na sua implementação de pausa). Se você se referia à segunda (que eu acho mais provável), a resposta aceita te explica tudo em detalhes técnicos mas a essência tá em: "*produza menos lixo e faça o GC trabalhar a seu favor*".

Em um jogo, "produzir lixo" é criar objetos (isto é, alocar memória) e depois jogá-los fora (isto é, deixar de referenciar aquela memória). É algo muito fácil de acontecer. Por exemplo, imagine um jogo simples em que você atira em aviões com uma bateria antiaérea a partir do solo. O jogo constantemente irá instanciar:

1. Aviões
2. Projéteis lançados pela bateria antiaérea

Os aviões e os projéteis são ambos destruídos quando o primeiro é atingido pelo segundo, certo? Além disso, os aviões eventualmente sairão da tela se não forem atingidos, assim como os projéteis sairão da tela se não atingirem um alvo. Se você instanciar novos objetos dessas classes e destruí-los quando ocorrer um impacto ou quando saírem da tela, você *não terá* vazamentos de memória (isto é, memória eternamente presa e inutilizável), e o seu jogo funcionará super bem. Para jogos simples, em que poucos desses objetos são instanciados, você não precisa se preocupar e pode deixar o GC fazer o trabalho dele da forma que foi projetado.

Mas e se o seu jogo é suficientemente complexo para você precisar ter muitos desses objetos? Nesse caso, talvez não faça sentido criar e destruir os objetos continuamente, pois a carga sobre o GC será muito grande e constante (isto é, você estará produzindo muito lixo e não estará fazendo o GC trabalhar a seu favor). Uma alternativa nesses casos é utilizar "tanques" (*pools* em inglês) de objetos pré-criados que são realocados depois de utilizados (por exemplo, a mesma bala que sai da tela é feita invisível e "transportada" novamente para a boca do canhão para ser disparada novamente).

Deixar objetos pré-criados ajuda no desempenho porque não sobrecarrega o GC, mas é claro que a memória tem seus limites e você não pode simplesmente deixar esse "tanque" crescer indefinidamente. Por isso realocar os objetos costuma ser uma boa prática.

Enfim, isso tem que ser feito com cuidado, considerando não apenas os aspectos técnicos aqui discutidos, mas também a experiência do jogador (que é algo muito importante nesse tipo de software). Um exemplo clássico é o dos buracos de bala deixados nas paredes do CounterStrike. Eles provavelmente são objetos mantidos em um desses tipos de "tanques" e são realocados quando o "tanque" se esgota. Funciona bem, mas já causou quebra de imersão em jogadores que tentaram literalmente escrever em paredes com os tiros (as letras iniciais iam sumindo conforme os objetos dos buracos de bala eram realocados). :)

Comment: Muito boa explicação do *object pool* que é útil também mesmo quando se opta por gerenciamento por *malloc/free-like*.

Answer (score 11):

Especificamente para o Java, há dois itens que eu destacaria sobre o assunto:

Primeiro, o GC do Java não é um mistério. Na verdade, existe mais de um e cada um com configurações diferentes que podem atender à demandas específicas, pois alguns tendem a ter pausas menores e frequentes enquanto outros pausas demoradas e raras. Além de pequenas técnicas e padrões que evitam o a criação e subsequente descarte desnecessário de objetos, se você desenvolve um jogo sério, você vai analisar a memória necessária em cada parte do jogo, monitorar as pausas, e simplesmente tentar alocar a memória suficiente para a JVM de modo que não seja necessário pausar a execução num momento inapropriado, possivelmente invocando o GC entre fases ou estágios do Jogo.

Segundo, existem otimizações mais avançadas usando memória alocada diretamente. Veja a documentação do [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). Além disso grande parte dos componentes visuais pode ser gerenciado também via integração com drivers nativos, tal como memória das placas de vídeo, que não são gerenciadas pelo GC.

Enfim, não estou argumentando que Java é uma linguagem apropriada para jogos, muito menos jogos grandes, até porque GC é apenas um fator. Entretanto, se você sabe o que está fazendo - e certamente um jogo sério precisará de um especialista na plataforma usada - pausas do GC provavelmente não serão sua a maior preocupação.